# Connection String for Ms Access in ADF Linked Service

Tags: ms-access, odbc, database-connection, azure-data-factory, connection-string

I have been trying to create MS Access Database Linked Service in Azure Data Factory.

The format I have been using is

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\server\share\folder\myAccessFile.mdb;`.

I cannot establish the connection between Azure Data Factory and MS Access Database through Linked Service.

It shows the below error when I am trying to create the linked service

`ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

If anyone knows how to resolve the issue and create the linked service in Azure Data Factory. Please Let me know.

Comment: That is an OLEDB connection string. The corresponding ODBC connection string would look like `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=\\server\share\folder\myAccessFile.mdb;`

Comment: I have tried this connection string also but it shows the same error ```ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified```

Comment: So it sounds like that machine does not have the Access ODBC driver installed.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to test the linked server connection using the below connection string.

Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, .accdb)};Dbq=D:\access\Nutritiondb.accdb;

or you can use the network path on the Dbq name

Ex:
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, .accdb)};Dbq=\DESKTOP-name\access\Nutritiondb.accdb;

[image]

Please check your access driver

[image]